# Property or Indexer 'ReportDocument.reportSource'cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have the following code for export a CrystalReport to PDF:

```
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load(@"C:\temp\ExportVacumeren\ExportVacumeren.rpt");

        VacuumByDayCrystalReport1.ReportSource = cryRpt;

        VacuumByDayCrystalReport1.Refresh();
        cryRpt.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"C:\temp\ExportVacumeren\" + Global.Day + " - " + Global.JaWe + " Vacumeren.pdf");
        MessageBox.Show("Exported Vacumeren Successful");
```

The line "VacuumByDayCrystalReport1.ReportSource = cryRpt;" gives me the error ***Property or Indexer 'ReportDocument.reportSource'cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.***
In my Crystal report for Visual Studio i have no option to change it.

Comment: If you look in the documentation for that property, it is likely shown as a Read Only property (i.e., it only has a `Get`ter).  There is probably a function you can use to change whatever that represents.

Comment: I'm totally stuck and don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Do you have documentation for whatever the type of `VacuumByDayCrystalReport1` is?  If I google for `crystal report type reportsource` (in Bing), I get lots of folks trying to set this.  You'll need to do some research

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i'm try already for days Google. maybe is this a brige to far for me ;)

Comment: Does, for example, this help: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/449238/Crystal-Reports-Report-Source-problem.  I can't help you much more than randomly suggesting links

Comment: :-( nothing is working